# How do I solve $\sin z - \cos z = 3$

Tags: complex-numbers

The original one is:

$$\sin z - \cos z = 3$$

by defenition:

$$\left(\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}-\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}\right) = 3$$

$$\left(\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{i} - e^{iz}+e^{-iz}\right) = 6$$

$$\left( \frac{e^{iz}-ie^{iz}-ie^{-iz}}{i} \right) = 6$$

What am I suposed to do next? I am not sure that it is right direction at all, i wass thinking of represention of $e$ via eulur's formula but it seems it makes the proccess even more complicated...

Comment: I think you're missing a term in the last line.

Comment: Also, you need a parentheses around the second fraction; you didn't distribute the minus.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better the following.

Let $z=x+yi$, where $\{x,y\}\subset\mathbb R$ and you'll get an easy system.

Indeed, we have
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x-yi\right)=\frac{3}{\sqrt2}$$ or
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)\cdot\frac{e^y+e^{-y}}{2}-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)\cdot\frac{e^y-e^{-y}}{2}i=\frac{3}{\sqrt2}$$
and the rest is smooth.

If $e^y=e^{-y}$ then $y=0$, which is impossible.

Thus, $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)=0$ and from here $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)=1$ because $-1$ is impossible.

Thus, $e^y+e^{-y}=3\sqrt2$ and it gives the answer.

Comment: do I understand correcntly that you applied two firmulas? sum of $\sin$ arg and sum of $\cos$ arg and then represented comples parts through $e$?

Comment: @M.Mass Yes, of course!

Comment: You seem to be missing the factor of  $\sqrt2$ in your first formula.

Comment: @Henning Makholm It was my mistake. I fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The usual trick is to recognize your formula is just a rational function in the variable $e^{iz}$ with complex coefficients. So:

- Make a substitution $w = e^{iz}$
- Solve the new equation for $w$
- For each solution $w=w_0$, solve $w_0 = e^{iz}$ for $z$

*Exercise:* Prove that every solution $z = z_0$ to the original equation can be obtained this way.

*Exercise:* Prove that every $z = z_0$ obtained this way is a solution to the original equation

Comment: I think it's a very ugly way. It was my first solution. See please my editing.